# recognizing rectangular area in an image

Tags: image-processing, opencv

This sounds like simple thing to do but I am having many issues with it.

By Hough transformation, I think I can get the ROI from the image. But because of our 3D world and my imperfect hand coordination, the ROI is skew, or has perspective projection - that is, it is not a real rectangle for further analysis.

Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: IF you provide an image example I could redirect you to interesting SO posts that deal with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `getPerspectiveTransform()` and `warpPerspective()` to make it into a rectangle again.

```
//cornerpoints contains the Point2f corners you detected in the image in clockwise ordering from top left
int rectheight=480;
int rectwidth=640;
Point2f rectpoints[4];
rectpoints[0]=Point2f(0,0);
rectpoints[1]=Point2f(0,rectwidth);
rectpoints[2]=Point2f(rectheight,rectwidth);
rectpoints[3]=Point2f(rectheight,0);
Mat pt=getPerspectiveTransform(cornerpoints,rectpoints);
Mat rectangle(rectheight,rectwidth,CV_8U);
warpPerspective(image,rectangle,pt,Size(rectheight,rectwidth));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using shape signature as proposed by Gonzalez in his book? It is easy and fast to calculate, if you have your shapes already segmented and labelled.

[This paper may also help](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165168411001976)